# How to programmatically link UITabBar with Different ViewControllers with NIBs when UITabBar is NOT rootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, uitabbar

I have a tableViewController that once tapped on a cell it takes you to `FirstViewController`FirstViewController has a UITabBar with 4 items. I want to programmatically hook each of those buttons/items to viewController that already exist in my project.

I have done a lot of research but haven't arrived at something that address this problem

What I have so far is `FirstViewController, SecondViewController, ThirdViewController, FourthViewController`

in `FirstViewController.xib` I have the TabBar with 4 icons.

```
FirstViewController.h

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarItem *tabBar;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarItem *firstItem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarItem *secondItem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarItem *thirdItem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarItem *fourthItem;

FirstViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    FirstViewController *first = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    ThirdViewController *third = [[ThirdViewController alloc] init];
    FourthViewController *fourth = [[FourthViewController alloc] init];

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject: first, second, third, fourth, nil];

}
```

This code doesn't work when I tab on the fourth button for example it doesn't show the `fourthViewController` nib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each **UIViewController** subclass has an associated **.xib** *(nib)* then use the designated initialiser.

Instead of `[[FirstViewController alloc] init]` use **initWithNibName:bundle:** for each respective view controller instead.

example -

```
[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nameOfNibFile" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: I changed my code to `FirstViewController *first = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];` but it still doesn't work. @Bamsworld

Comment: Ah I see, the implementation you have in FirstViewController should be in its own UITabBarController subclass (which I see you have an outlet to one) that imports the headers of the view controllers you wish to add to it. I know your doing it programatically, but it may be worth quickly starting a new project with the tab bar template and look at the storyboard to understand better how it all hooks up.